# jquery replace syntax not functioning

Tags: jquery, replace

HI have a simple need to generate a new window with the contents of a textarea. Based on which type of formatting a user wants, they can push a button to alter some of the textarea 'text' to suit their needs. But I am having trouble with implementing the .replace command - though I've tried to follow examples on this forum.

```
    <body>
    <div id="diagoutput"> </div>

<a onclick="combine()" href="report_output.html" id="link" target="_blank"><input type="button" value="Generate a report window"><br>

  <textarea rows="10" cols="40" placeholder="Diagnosis" id="outPut3">I love the sun devils</textarea><br>

    </body>
```

And here is my js snippet that is not replacing the intended text

```
function combine(){
    var diag=$("#outPut3").text().replace(/sun devils/g, "WILDCATS");
    var textToPass=' \nNEW TEXT:\n'+diag.value;
    localStorage.setItem("myText", textToPass);
};
```

I'm new with jQuery, so some of my attempts to copy what others have done may be a bit crude.

I appreciate any help,
ck

Comment: can u create a http://fiddle.net for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the content of the textarea, don't use `text` but `val`, and don't try to call `value` on the `diag` variable as it's a string, not a jQuery element :

```
var diag=$("#outPut3").val().replace(/sun devils/g, "WILDCATS");
var textToPass=' \nNEW TEXT:\n'+diag;
localStorage.setItem("myText", textToPass);
```

If you want to change the content to the replaced string, use `val` again :

```
$("#outPut3").val(textToPass);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! One question, if I used 'text()' instead of val(), what would be stored in the 'var diag='? If not the text, then what?

Comment: The initial value of the text, not the current textarea value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code fine.  The only mistake is `diag.value`, you can have

```
var textToPass=' \nNEW TEXT:\n'+diag;
```

Incase if you want to in the `textarea`, then change your code like below.

```
var diag= $("#outPut3").text().replace(/sun devils/g, "WILDCATS");
$("#outPut3").text(diag);
```

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fnA6M/)